# Why is there an error comming up, that says a variable is undefined. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have an indicator of how fast you are moving as a UI element. however, I get an error that states: Cannot use local variable 'lastPosition' before it is declared. The declaration of the local variable hides the field 'scoreScript.lastPosition'.

Ive tried many different ways, getting a lot of errors (as i am pretty new to the unity coding language) and this one made the most sense to me, sadly there is still this one error.

```
Text shownScore;
public GameObject player;
Vector3 lastPosition;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    lastPosition = player.transform.position;
    shownScore = GetComponent<Text>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 offset =  player.transform.position - lastPosition;
    shownScore.text = offset.sqrMagnitude.ToString("#.00");
    Vector3 lastPosition = player.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Remove `Vector3` before `lastPosition` **in the `Update` method**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using:

```
Vector3 lastPosition = player.transform.position;
```

you are declaring a new local variable named `lastPosition`. This local variable overrides the `lastPosition` in your `scoreScript` and you'll get an error message when using it. Instead just use the same `lastPosition`:

```
lastPosition = player.transform.position;
```